# Getting files for the current date in Linux?

Tags: linux, files, date, timestamps

Usually the `date +%d` gives the output `08` for the current date, 08/10/2017. But when I do the `ls -lrt` on a path, the date format is like `Oct  8 15:03`, so, how do I get the files of the current date?

I'm using the command

```
ls -lrt XYZ.LOG* |grep "$(date +'%b %d')" |awk '{print $9}'
```

but it's not giving me the file of today's date (08/10/2017) although it gives me correct output for the dates 10 - 31st of any month.

Answer (score 7):

This is cheating a bit, but it works.

First create an empty reference file with a specific timestamp, namely midnight:

```
touch -d "$(date +%FT00:00:00)" /tmp/midnight
```

Then find files that are newer than this file:

```
find . -type f -newer /tmp/midnight
```

If you want `ls`-like output from `find` rather than just the pathnames:

```
find . -type f -newer /tmp/midnight -ls
```

If you want to find files matching the pattern `XYZ.LOG*`:

```
find . -type f -name 'XYZ.LOG*' -newer /tmp/midnight -ls
```

---

If you have GNU `find`, you may bypass the temporary file and use

```
find . -type f -newermt 0
```

to get files modified since midnight.

---

Related: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: At least with recent versions of GNU `find`, you can skip the temp file and use time strings directly with the `-newerXY` test e.g. `find . -type f -newermt yesterday`

Comment: @steeldriver Ah, but `yesterday` would refer to "this time yesterday" which may cause files modified before midnight to be returned.

Comment: @steeldriver `0` works though...

Comment: getting error: `$ touch -d "$(date +%FT00:00:00)" /tmp/midnight
touch: illegal option -- d
usage: touch [-amc] [-t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS] | -r ref_file] file ...`

Comment: @User123 What Linux are you running? Are you using busybox? The `-d` flag is a POSIX standard flag.  Oh well, change that line to `touch -t "$(date +%Y%m%d0000)" /tmp/midnight`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stat(1)` to get the modified time of a file, but this is not portable.

On Linux:

```
$ stat -c %y some_file
2017-09-23 10:24:09.880806666 +0200

$ date -d @$(stat -c %Y some_file) +%d-%m-%Y
23-09-2017
```

On BSD:

```
$ stat -f %Sm -t %d-%m-%Y some_file
23-09-2017
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to get the files of the current date?

**ls** command has `--time-style` option to print the time in specific format:

```
ls -l --time-style=+'%d-%m-%Y' | awk -v d=$(date +%d-%m-%Y) '$6==d'
```

---

> **`--time-style`**=*STYLE*
>             with  `-l`,  show  times using style STYLE: full-iso, long-iso, iso, locale, or +FORMAT; FORMAT is interpreted like in
>             `'date'`;

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, using glob qualifiers and [`age`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Calendar-Function-System.html#Glob-qualifiers):

```
autoload age
print -rl ./**/XYZ.LOG*(e_'age today now'_)
```

or, if you prefer the long listing format:

```
autoload age
ls -lrtd -- **/XYZ.LOG*(e_'age today now'_)
```

Comment: Note that it will not list files with `mtime` in the future but still today, so after whatever `now` is when you run the command until `00:00:00` tommorow. To get those too remove the argument `now`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
echo `date +'%Y-%m-%d'`*
```

Comment: The question, while unclear,  does not appear to be about files *whose name begins with today’s date.*